# Обработка событий в Custom View (отрисовка на Canvas) через кнопки-виджеты Button

Tags: java, android

Я создал свой Custom View, на котором рисую, и разместил его на одном экране вместе с кнопками-виджетами. Как мне сделать так, чтобы через нажатия на кнопки происходили какие-то преобразования на Canvas моего View?

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Custom View:

```
public class CustomView extends View {

    private Paint mPaint = new Paint();

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawARGB(80, 102, 204, 255);
        canvas.drawRect(getWidth()/2-125, getHeight()/2-25, getWidth()/2-75, getHeight()/2+25, mPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(getWidth()/2-25, getHeight()/2-25, getWidth()/2+25, getHeight()/2+25, mPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(getWidth()/2+75, getHeight()/2-25, getWidth()/2+125, getHeight()/2+25, mPaint);
    }
}
```

activity_main:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ru.cirq.myapplication1.CustomView
        android:id="@+id/myCustomView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button2"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button3"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Я для примера сразу нарисовал три черных квадратика по центру экрана. Допустим, как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на button1 появлялся первый квадрат, при нажатии на button2 - второй и, аналогично, третий?

Я знаю, что через обработчик onTouchEvent() можно тыкать прям по экрану в области моего CustomView и назначать там нужные действия, но мне нужно реализовать именно через кнопки-виджеты button.

Answer (score 4):

Я на самом деле не понимаю, почему у вас вызвало затруднения при помощи кнопок выбирать, какой квадрат рисовать, если вы вообще смогли нарисовать эти квадраты. Тут используется самая обычная логика:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        customView.drawSquare(1);
        //передаем в customView, какой именно квадрат рисовать
    }
});
```

В `CustomView`:

```
private int drawingSquare  = 0;

public void drawSquare(int drawingSquare) {
    this.drawingSquare = drawingSquare; // запоминаем, какой квадрат рисовать
    invalidate();// говорим CustomView, чтобы он перерисовался
}

@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawARGB(80, 102, 204, 255);
        if(drawingSquare == 1) { //Если нужно рисовать первый квадрат, то рисуем только его
            canvas.drawRect(getWidth()/2-125, getHeight()/2-25, getWidth()/2-75, getHeight()/2+25, mPaint);
        } else if(drawingSquare == 2) { //Если нужно рисовать второй квадрат, то рисуем только его
            canvas.drawRect(getWidth()/2-25, getHeight()/2-25, getWidth()/2+25, getHeight()/2+25, mPaint);
        } else if(drawingSquare == 3) { //Если нужно рисовать третий квадрат, то рисуем только его
            canvas.drawRect(getWidth()/2+75, getHeight()/2-25, getWidth()/2+125, getHeight()/2+25, mPaint);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо. Мне, знаю, надо теорию Java учить.

Comment: Не могли бы вы подсказать почему у меня ошибка всё-равно выходит? В MainActivity пишет Non-static method 'drawSquare(int)'cannot be referenced from a static context. А если я меняю метод на статичный в CustomView пишет '...CustomView.this' cannot be referenced from a static context.

Comment: @Alexey, никто не знает, как вы используете ваш `CustomView`